# Join consecutive number values from start to end reduced with the resembling start characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I thought this would be possible by the use of lambda formulas (REDUCE, SCAN, MAP, OFFSET), but I'm lost where to start even.

How can I generate the result in cell C2 with lambda formulas?

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  | result |
| **2** | 23001 |  | 23001-4; 23006-10; 23014-7; 23028-9; 23037; 23041-3; 23046; 23049 |
| **3** | 23002 |  |  |
| **4** | 23003 |  |  |
| **5** | 23004 |  |  |
| **6** | 23006 |  |  |
| **7** | 23007 |  |  |
| **8** | 23008 |  |  |
| **9** | 23009 |  |  |
| **10** | 23010 |  |  |
| **11** | 23014 |  |  |
| **12** | 23015 |  |  |
| **13** | 23016 |  |  |
| **14** | 23017 |  |  |
| **15** | 23028 |  |  |
| **16** | 23029 |  |  |
| **17** | 23037 |  |  |
| **18** | 23041 |  |  |
| **19** | 23042 |  |  |
| **20** | 23043 |  |  |
| **21** | 23046 |  |  |
| **22** | 23049 |  |  |

Since 230001 to 230004 are consecutive numbers, these values are reduced to the start value (23001) and the ending value (23004) of the consecutive range,.

The end value needs to be shortened up to the position of the first character that does not match the same character of the start value with a `-` in between the two.

So this would mean that with values `230001` (start) and `230004` (end) the characters `23000` all match between the start and end value, but character `4` does not equal character `1`, therefore this character and possible trailing characters need to be shown from the end value only.

If there are no consecutive numbers than only show the start value, `230001-4` is written.

Likewise, 230006 to 230010 are consecutive numbers, and would result in 230006-10

230014 is written alone because it is not consecutive

etc...

I need this array combined as textjoin, where the individual consecutive ranges as explained above are separated by `;` .

I tried to create formula with reduce lambda but failed

Comment: We need more information.  please create a [mcve] by [edit]ing the post to include a markdown table with test data and expected results.  With what you gave we do not know from where the count comes.

Comment: Sir i need this output

230001-4; 230006-10; 230014; 230016-17; 230028-29; 230037; 230041-43; 230046; 230049

which gets clubbed before each missin numbers

ike if there is a number sequence missing then the above will be closed, again if there is a missing the next will  be clubbed

Comment: @VetExc Scott means you need to edit your post and frame this differently. Even your comment it is unclear the logic you're trying to get at. Try to explain what needs to happen in C2. Seems like textcombine, but the -4, etc. is unclear where this comes from or what it is. Write this for people completely unfamiliar with your process to get up to speed.

Comment: Since 230001 to 230004 are consecutive numbers, 230001-4 is written. Likewise, since 230006 to 230010 are consecutive numbers, 230006-10 is written ... 230014 is written alone because it is not consecutive... etc... You specified Like this array should be combined as textjoin. In fact, everything looks clear and clear in the uploaded picture.

Comment: Do not put clarifications in the comments.  Instead [edit] the post to include those clarifications.

Comment: ok. Sir. Thanks your interested.

Comment: I changed the formulation of your question, since it's quite a nice problem, but it was poorly described.

Comment: I don't know how to use the forum. Thanks for editing the query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=LET(data,  A2:A22,
     s,     MAP(    data,
            LAMBDA( d,
                    IFERROR(
                            IF( OFFSET(d,-1,)+1<>d,
                                d,
                                ""),
                            d))),
     e,     MAP(    data,
            LAMBDA( d,
                    IFERROR(
                            IF( OFFSET(d,1,)-1<>d,
                                d,
                                ""),
                            d))),
     start, FILTER(s, s<>""),
     end,   FILTER(e, e<>""),
     len,   LEN(start),
     m,     MAP(    start, end, len,
            LAMBDA( a,     b,   l,
                    MATCH(TRUE,
                          (MID(a,SEQUENCE(l),1)<>MID(b,SEQUENCE(l),1)),
                          0))),
TEXTJOIN("; ",
         1,
         IF( ISERROR(m),
             start,
             start & "-" & MID( end, m, LEN(end)))))
```

[image]

This uses `MAP` to spill the `start` values and another `MAP` to spill the end values in the range.

A 3rd `MAP` is used to check position of the first character of the `end` value to equal the start value to later use it in a `MID` formula, to start the end value from that position.

Not sure if using OFFSET inside the LET causes it to be volatile (it could be replaced with INDEX, I just didn't).

Comment: It was a nice challenge

Answer (score 2):

I cannot get you exactly what you want but I can get close:

```
=REDUCE("",A2:A21,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a="",b,IF(LEN(a)=LEN(b),IF(a+1=b,a&"-"&b,a&"; "&b),IF(--IFERROR(RIGHT(a,LEN(b&"")),0)=b-1,IF(MID(a,LEN(a)-LEN(b),1)=" ",a&"-"&b,LEFT(a,MAX(LEN(a)-LEN(b),0))&b),a&"; "&b)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, the solution you gave is very close to the desired result. your approach to this answer is also very good.. but it would be much better if it could be the formula that actually gives the desired result. Thanks again for your support and solution.

Comment: If I could get to what you wanted I would have posted that.  This is as close as I could get.